# How can I change the value where char* is Pointing?

Tags: c, pointers

I am using `char*` to store some variable values, but there's problem that I can't change its value. If anyone could suggest a method..... Would be a life saver for me....

```
char* year=""; //definition as empty
get_data(){
  year=  //"Here I want to give it another value of another variable(also in char*)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer (don't do this):

```
#include <string.h>
...
strcpy(year, "your new string");
```

The reason not to do this is that you don't own the memory that `year` is pointing to. Instead, you should declare `year` as `char year[100]`, this allocates memory for you on the stack. Then you can copy a string into it.

Answer (score -1):

```
char year[1024] = {0}; // Null terminated, so empty string.
get_data() {
    strcpy(year, "some value");
}
```

Comment: @GustavoMori: it's always better to answer what they need to know than what they're asking. Foundation of modern schooling.